# Заполнить поле значением из предыдущей строки

Tags: sql, update

Есть таблица:

[image: таблица1]

Как в базе данных MySQL запросом заполнить в таблице пустые поля (обновить таблицу) по принципу:

- Находим пустые поля в строке
- Заполняем их значениями из предыдущей строки

Много статей прочитал, но разобраться не смог.

Comment: А что такое "предыдущая строка" ? Дайте точное определение такой строки и тогда должно стать понятно как написать update.

Comment: Предыдущая - означает: строка у которой id меньше на 1

Запрос с селектом работает, а вот переписать его в UPDATE пока не выходит

SET @a = '';
SELECT `id`,(CASE `marka` WHEN '' THEN @a ELSE @a := `marka` END) as `marka` FROM `TABLE 2`

Comment: А что если в БД нет записи с id меньшим на 1 и что делать если в предыдущей строке требуемое поле то же NULL ? Дайте определение из какой строки взять значение для изменения например строки id=9

Comment: - перем первую строку
- если поле marka заполнено (а у первой строки оно точно заполнено), то сохраняем его значение в переменную
- берем вторую строку, если поле пустое, то вставляем в него значение из переменной, если поле заполнено, то перезаписываем переменную

Comment: для строки id=9 мы берем значение из строки id=8 (а поскольку в первой строке значение есть и все строки до 9 мы уже заполнили, то в строке id=8 точно есть значение)

Answer (score 1):

О, разобрался:

```sql
SET @a = ' ';

UPDATE `TABLE` 
SET `marka` = (CASE `marka` WHEN '' THEN @a ELSE @a := `marka` END)
```

Comment: order by только добавьте, без него порядок записей не гарантирован ...